# Rails: Human-friendly date format for text_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I have a birth_date field that is stored as a datetime value. The default rails form helpers spit out a not-too-friendly format, e.g. "2008-06-10 22:33:19.000000". The below is the vanilla rails way.

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :birth_date %>
  <%= f.text_field :birth_date, :size=>"20" %>
</div>
```

How can I simply apply a format? I tried various approaches, for example strftime should work, I thought. But when I try the following, I get an error `undefined method 'strftime' for nil:NilClass`

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :birth_date %>
  <%= f.text_field :birth_date, :value=>f.object.birth_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'), :size=>"20" %>
</div>
```

Based on some other questions/answers, I tried the following. It works for non-null values, but it is ugly code, and it doesn't work for blank values (actually it shows today's date).

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :birth_date %>
  <%= f.text_field :birth_date, :value=> Time.parse(f.object.birth_date.to_s).strftime('%m/%d/%Y'), :size=>"20" %>
</div>
```

In playing around, it seems that outputting f.object.birth_date is treated as a date, rather than datetime. However, when displayed in the text_field (original, ugly formatting), it includes the time. It is friday afternoon, and my combined lack of familiarity with rails forms and ruby date/time objects is making me feel foolish.

Any simple way to get my form to display nothing if null/blank, and a friendly date otherwise?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want a blank string if `birth_date` is empty, you should simply check that `birth_date` is non-`nil` beforehand:

```
<%= f.text_field :birth_date, :value => (f.object.birth_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') if f.object.birth_date), :size => "20" %>
```

This way, when birth_date is `nil`, `:value` gets set to `nil`.

Comment: Thanks, does what I need. I was confused why this doesn't throw an error when doing it without the nil check does. I think I have it sorted now. This does what I want (though still seems like a lot of code).

Comment: You're welcome.  The reason why it throws an error without the `nil` check is because when `f.object.birth_date` is `nil`, you'll try calling `strftime` on it.  Because `nil` doesn't have a `strftime` method, it throws the error.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using the `date_select` form builder helper method? You can also use `datetime_select`, but it looks like you just want to work with the date here.

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :birth_date %>
  <%= f.date_select :birth_date %>
</div>
```

The API docs are here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select
Add on the options you need.

I've always used that approach, or a javascript date selector like [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) one from jQuery UI. There are plugins for most JS frameworks these days.

If it MUST be a text_field, use a human language date parsing library like [chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic/). It'll work, but will require that you parse the input from the form somewhere before applying the attribute to your object.

Comment: I will eventually go to a date picker. Thanks for sharing the date_select, I hadn't used that before. However, I don't love that as an interface. Typing a human text date seems better. I personally prefer a hybrid of a javascript-enabled picker that also lets you hand type a date (like the jquery option you pointed out).